# Difference between java class and jar

Tags: java, class, jar

What is the difference between a java class file and a jar file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A Jar file is an Zip archive containing one or multilple java class files. This makes the usage of libraries (consisting of multiple classes) more handy. Directories and Jar files are  added to the classpath and available to the `ClassLoader` at runtime to find particular classes inside of it.

Comment: Strictly speaking a jar file can also contain 0 classes (for example if it contains only resources).

Comment: @JoachimSauer you mean class files?

Comment: @Fakipo: I meant that a jar file can contain zero class files and still be valid. It would be unusual, but allowed. A class file will always contain exactly one type (class, interface, enum, ...).

Answer (score 32):

A **JAR** file has many files into it. We generally use .jar files to distribute Java applications or libraries, in the form of Java class files and associated metadata and resources (text, images, etc.). you can say ***JAR =  Java ARchive***.

All java files are compiled into class files and then we use that class file not the .java file. A class is a construct that is used as a blueprint to create instances of the class.

See Wikipedia for more information: [Wikipedia for JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) and [Wikipedia for class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29)

Answer (score 7):

A java file contains Java code. A Java file is compiled to produce a class file that can be loaded by the JVM. The contents of a class file are rather well explained [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1996/jw-07-classfile.html). A Jar file is an archive of otherfile, most likely class files.

Comment: So is the .java file compiled into a .class when you create the .jar file or do you need to compile the .java file via the IDE before creating the .jar?

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work for me now

Answer (score 2):

JAR file is the compressed file format. You can store many files in a JAR file. JAR stands for the Java Archive. This file format is used to distribute a set of java classes. This file helps you to reduce the file size and collect many file in one by compressing files

a Class is explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)