# Is .class file an executable file for JVM?

Tags: jvm, java

Use JDK , I can compile a **.java** file into a **.class** file, then I can run the **.class** file, does this mean that the **.class** file is the final executable file running on JVM ?
Moreover, what's a **jar** file ? and the difference between **jar** file and **.class** file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between java class and jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743768/difference-between-java-class-and-jar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** A class file is a `byte code files`, which is executed by the JVM, it has **no meaning outside the JVM.** Making it meaningful only on JVM but not outside, is what makes every java program run in its `own sandbox .`

**2.** Jar file is a **collection** of all the `class file`, `libraries` necessary to run the program, **consider its an easy way to pack all the files and depending library and providing a single file.** We also have `Runnable Jars` which can be known as `Executable Jar`

**////////// EDITED PART//////////////////**

Now this `byte-code` is converted to `machine level executable` during **Run-time** by the `JIT` (Just In Time Compiler). **JIT will look for the runtime intensive part of the program during Runtime**, and then it will convert it into machine level executable, **this part of the program is known as** `Hot-spot`, and the `JIT` is known as `Hot-Spot-Compiler`.

Comment: Thanks ! But how to make a **jar** file ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse for creating jar as well as Runnable jar

Comment: you mean a **Jar** is different from a **Executable Jar** ? if so , is there any use of a **Jar** ?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that a .jar file is actually just a .zip file with some .class (or .java, or both) files inside it.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my answer.. But still i want to clarify this... when we create a simple jar file, it means a way to pack different classes and libraries into a single file, But creating an Executable Jar will make your app run by double clicking it... but make sure its an GUI app, cause command line program needs to be executed from commond line itself

Comment: Bin_Z, Java libraries are commonly distributed as .jar files, so a single project might rely on several non-executable 3rd party .jar files.

Comment: @Zofrex i have mentioned that, saying that its an easy way to pack all the class and dependent libraries

Comment: @Bin_Z there are n number of tutorials on net regarding creating an Jar or Runnable Jar using eclipse...thats the easy way to go... Doing the same from command line may be sometimes difficult for someone new at it

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra I don't mean it's like a .zip file, I mean it actually is a .zip file! Rename a .jar to .zip and see :)

Comment: @ZoFreX thats like writing into a .txt file and convert the extension to doc.... zip is different than jar cause jar maintains extra information and hence an application or tool can use that information for an intelligent processing of the contents of the 'jar' file. For example: a 'jar' file can be made executable and the tool will automatically check the MANIFEST file to get the class file whose main() method will be run to start the execution.

Comment: It's not quite the same as saving a .txt as a .doc, a .jar file is actually a .zip file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29

Answer (score 1):

A jar (java archive) as its name says is an archive or collection of java classes that are ready to be executed.

A java decompiler is a tool that makes a reverse engineering from .class extension to .java extension.

To make a jar  use following link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Or using windows command promt

```
jar cf JAR_FILE_NAME FILE_NAMES_OR_DIRECTORY_NAME
e.g.
jar cf MyApp1.jar C:\JavaProject\MyApp
```